# How are pairs stored in memory in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, iteration, key-pair

I was  just reading about pairs in C++ when this doubt stroke my mind that how the pairs are stored in memory and id the identifier assigned to the pairs a object or something else.
pls explain how an array containing pair uses memory to save the pairs and how can we iterate through the that array, by accessing each pair;

Comment: In C++, an array or pairs is stored literally like that. You can also have a pair of arrays (`std::pair<std::array<T1, N1>, std::array<T2, N2>>`), but that's an entirely different type with a different memory layout. In particular, since the latter contains two arrays, the two arrays can have different sizes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for the pair itself, if you take a look at the standard library [source code](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_pair.h#L198) you'll just notice, that after cutting all the boilerplate, the for the most trivial case `std::pair` is just a simple class template:

```
template<typename First, typename Second>
struct pair
{
  First first;
  Second second;
};
```

Now, all the boilerplate is there to ensure the all the special functions like comparison, assignment, copy construction etc. are performed with minimal overhead.
But for the sake of mental model one can think of this simple struct.

As for "array of pairs" - I'm not sure I follow, really.
`std::array<std::pair<X,Y>, SIZE>`/`std::vector<std::pair<X,Y>>` behaves just as it would for any other type, i.e. it store the pairs in contiguous memory block, end of story.
Same about iteration, there's nothing special about it:

```cpp
    std::array<std::pair<char, int>, 3> pairs{
        std::pair{'a', 1},
        std::pair{'b', 2},
        std::pair{'c', 3}};

    for (const auto& p:pairs){
        std::cout << p.first << " " << p.second << "\n";
    }
```

[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/je4e7MTex)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <iterator>


int main( )
{
    std::array< std::pair<char, char>, 10 > arrayOfPairs { };
    std::cout << "size of array: " << sizeof( arrayOfPairs ) << "\n\n";

    for ( size_t idx { }; idx < arrayOfPairs.size( ); ++idx) // fill the array with
                                                             // std::pair objects
    {
        arrayOfPairs[ idx ] = std::make_pair<char, char>( 'a', 'b' + idx );
    }

    std::cout << "key" << "   " << "value" << '\n';

    for ( const auto& p : arrayOfPairs ) // print the keys and values
    {
        std::cout << " " << p.first << "      " << p.second << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
size of array: 20

key   value
 a      b
 a      c
 a      d
 a      e
 a      f
 a      g
 a      h
 a      i
 a      j
 a      k
```

In this example, each pair object consists of two `char`s, so the size is **2** bytes. `arrayOfPairs` has the space for **10** pair objects which means that its size is **10 * 2 == 20** bytes. In an `std::pair` object, the key and its value are stored besides each other. It acts like a simple struct.

Comment: how does this answer the question?

Comment: The "contiguous" bit is misleading if not wrong. In standard C++ parlance, "contiguous" means "without padding". That is to say, the address of the second object is the address of the first subobject plus the size of the first subobject. This cannot be guaranteed in general because of alignment. It's likely that a `pair<char,int>` has internal padding.

Comment: @MSalters True. And yes, on my compiler a `pair<char, int>` has a size of 8 bytes instead of 5.

Comment: but this does not explain how a pair is stored

Comment: @Vasu saini What do you mean by "how a pair is stored"?